# How to price an Annuity

Tags: fixed-income, quantlib, annuity

When we price a fixed rate bond using `Quantlib`, we generally take below approach -

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd

todaysDate = ql.Date(31, 8, 2019)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate

spotDates = [ql.Date(1,9,2019), ql.Date(5,9,2019), ql.Date(7,9,2019)]
spotRates = [0.066682, 0.067199, 0.067502]

dayCount = ql.Actual365Fixed()
calendar = ql.SouthAfrica()
interpolation = ql.Linear()
compounding = ql.Compounded
compoundingFrequency = ql.Semiannual

spotCurve = ql.ZeroCurve(spotDates, spotRates, dayCount, calendar, interpolation, compounding, compoundingFrequency)
spotCurveHandle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(spotCurve)

issueDate = ql.Date(20, 4, 2017)
maturityDate = ql.Date(20, 4, 2019)
tenor = ql.Period(ql.Semiannual)
calendar = ql.SouthAfrica()
bussinessConvention = ql.Following
dateGeneration = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
monthEnd = False

schedule = ql.Schedule(issueDate, maturityDate, tenor, calendar, bussinessConvention, bussinessConvention, dateGeneration, monthEnd)

dayCount = ql.Actual365Fixed()
couponRate = 0.0925
coupons = [couponRate]

settlementDays = 3
faceValue = 100
fixedRateBond = ql.FixedRateBond(settlementDays, faceValue, schedule, coupons, dayCount)

bondEngine = ql.DiscountingBondEngine(spotCurveHandle)
fixedRateBond.setPricingEngine(bondEngine)

fixedRateBond.NPV()
```

However my question is - instead of a typical bond if I need to price the `Annuity` (i.e. there is no Principal payment at the maturity), how can I modify above codebase?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The bond engine uses the `CashFlows::npv()` method internally, so you can do the same after stripping the principal payment from the bond cashflows:

```
cashflows = fixedRateBond.cashflows()
coupons = cashflows[:-1] # all except the last

includeSettlementDateFlows = False

annuity = CashFlows.npv(
    coupons,
    spotCurveHandle,
    False,
    spotCurveHandle.referenceDate()
)
```

This will be consistent to `fixedRateBond.NPV()` (and you can verify it by *not* stripping the last coupon, i.e., setting `coupons = cashflows`: you'll get the same result).

However, note that this (and `fixedRateBond.NPV()`) discounts to the reference date of the spot curve, i.e., to the first of the `spotDates`.  If you want to discount to the settlement date of the bond, you should use instead

```
annuity = CashFlows.npv(
    coupons,
    spotCurveHandle,
    False,
    bond.settlementDate()
)
```

and you should also use `fixedRateBond.dirtyPrice()` instead of `fixedRateBond.NPV()`.

Comment: To add to Luigi's answer, you could also use the `FixedRateLeg` class and get just the coupons: `ql.FixedRateLeg(schedule, dayCount, [faceValue], [couponRate] )`

Comment: Thanks. What is the purpose of "includeSettlementDateFlows = False"

Comment: Additionally, I am getting error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'npv'"

Comment: About the error, careful not to confuse `CashFlows` (the class) with `cashflows` (the variable) in the above.  Capitalization matters.

Comment: With `includeSettlementDateFlows` set to `False` (the default), if a coupon pays today it's not included in the NPV.  If set to `True`, the coupon is included.